# T-SQL stored procedure: in while loop inside cursor only insert the first row from collection

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a problem with this stored procedure.

Parameters from my application are well defined, but in this procedure, when I am trying to insert a row into table `Image`, it insert only the first row from `@xmlImages` and I sent two values. I appreciate any help!

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_AddExplanationAndImage
    @Text NVARCHAR(MAX) = NULL,
    @ID INT = 0
    @ListOfImages NVARCHAR(MAX) = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dbo.Explanation (ID, Text)
    VALUES (@ID, @Text)

    DECLARE @xmlImages xml

    SET @xmlImages = CAST(@ListOfImages AS xml)

    DECLARE @ImageExtension NVARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @Name NVARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @Content VARBINARY(MAX)

    IF (@ListOfImages IS NOT NULL)
    BEGIN
        DECLARE cursor cursor for--local fast_forward for
            SELECT
                s.x.value('(Image/Extension)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'),
                s.x.value('(Image/Name)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'),
                s.x.value('(Image/Content)[1]', 'varbinary(max)')
            FROM 
                @xmlImages.nodes('Images') AS s(x)

        OPEN CURSOR

        FETCH NEXT FROM cursor INTO @ImageExtension, @Name, @Content 

        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        BEGIN
            IF @@fetch_status <> 0 
               BREAK

            INSERT INTO dbo.Image (Extension, Name, Content)
                SELECT @ImageExtension, @Name, @Content

            FETCH NEXT FROM cursorSlike INTO @ImageExtension, @Name, @Content 
        END

        CLOSE cursor
        DEALLOCATE cursor
    END
```

Comment: Could you also add your xml data?

Comment: and you dont need to use cursor. you can insert from xml select

Comment: This is my xml from code:
<Images>
    <Image>
         <Extension>jpg</Extension>
         <Name>picture1</Name>
         <Content>0x4C006A0069006C006A00610043005600</Content>
    </Image>
         <Image>
         <Extension>jpg</Extension>
         <Name>picture2</Name>
         <Content>0x4A006F00760061006E0043005600</Content>
    </Image>
</Images>

Comment: I tried also insert into table image from select in xml, but it gave me same results.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Thank you for advice! I will change that prefix!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your sample data. you need to get `Images/Image` nodes. And you dont need to use cursor.

```
    INSERT INTO dbo.Image(Extension,Name,Content)
    SELECT
        s.x.value('(Extension)[1]','nvarchar(max)'),
        s.x.value('(Name)[1]','nvarchar(max)'),
        s.x.value('(Content)[1]','nvarchar(max)')
    FROM @xmlImages.nodes('Images/Image')AS s(x)
```

Comment: Yes this solve my problem, I change my xpaths ! It was my mistake when i write this @xmlImages.nodes('Image')AS s(x) .Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

The `fetch next from` inside the `WHILE` block does not reference the cursor that you're looping through. You named your cursor `cursor` (I recommend using a more descriptive name BTW) but you're fetching next from `cursorSlike`.

But I'm not sure you need the loop in the first place (in general, you should avoid loops in SQL Server unless there's no other way to accomplish the task). I haven't done a lot with XML in SQL Server but have you tried this?

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Image(Extension,Name,Content)
 SELECT
            s.x.value('(Image/Extension)[1]','nvarchar(max)'),
            s.x.value('(Image/Name)[1]','nvarchar(max)'),
            s.x.value('(Image/Content)[1]','varbinary(max)')
        FROM @xmlImages.nodes('Images')AS s(x)
```

Comment: Yes i tried this, and also test in query window to see the results and it gave me only the first image from this xml:
DECLARE @xmlImage xml
SET @xmlImage=CAST('<Image>
  <Image>
    <Extension>jpg</Extension>
    <Name>14124198_1220921057958339_619735749_o</Name>
    </Image>
  <Image>
    <Extension>jpg</Extension>
    <Name>14124191_1220921161291662_714654791_o</Name>
   </Image>
</Images>' AS XML)

 SELECT
   s.x.value('(Image/Extension)[1]','nvarchar(max)'),
   s.x.value('(Image/Name)[1]','nvarchar(max)')
  FROM @xmlImage.nodes('Images')AS s(x)